# How to upload a file using selinium web driver?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to upload a file using selenium web driver. Browsing file working fine. But when upload a file to that localhost site I'got confuse. There is a upload button. Code is following way.

```
   <input type="submit" value="Upload" > </input>
```

I tried to use following both code.

```
   driver.findElement(By.name("UNSET FILE NAME")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Ontology.owl"); 

   driver.findElement(By.name("Upload")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("Upload")).click();
```

Both are not worked for me. Error message given as mentioning not that name or id. What should I have to change above code?

[image: Image of interface]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this code for uploading and clicking on the Upload button: (Assuming the element for uploading file is an 'input tag' with type 'file')**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Ontology.owl"); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Upload']")).click();
```

### Alternative:-

Below is an alternative to the above method. 
**Please only import the classes related to "java.awt" package, as "Robot, KeyEvent, StringSelection and Toolkit" will only work then**

```
    //Clicking on the Browse button
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).click();

    //Setting the Clipboard contents
    StringSelection path = new StringSelection("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Ontology.owl");//the code needed to be pasted in the second dialog box 
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(path, null);

    Thread.sleep(4000);//Sleep time to detect the window dialog box

    //Pasting the path in the File name field
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

    //To click the Open button so as to upload file
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

    //Click on Upload button
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Upload']")).click();
```

Comment: Now I think file is uploading. But finally display Error 404: Not Found message. And browser link as showing "http://localhost:3030/No session/upload". what's wrong with it?

Comment: This must be something related to site's functionality. When done manually, does the upload happen properly ?

Comment: Yep. Manually that works fine. I just browse and click upload button only.

Comment: How do you come to know that the upload was successful? Does it show any confirmation message or alert box or something ?

Comment: Sorry Actually file doesn't upload. I press back button and try to manually click the upload button. That time also same error given. But without loading site from selenium and manually load and I can upload. What's actual wrong?

Comment: Correct. When after load that site through selenium I tried press back button and manually upload. That also doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Maduri : I have updated my code with an alternative. See if that works for you and please let me know.

Comment: String PROXY = "localhost:3030";
  org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new          org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
  proxy.setHttpProxy(PROXY)
       .setFtpProxy(PROXY)
       .setSslProxy(PROXY);
  DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
  cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
  driver.get("http://localhost:3030/sparql.tpl");

Comment: Actually I changing my proxy also. Is that affect?

Comment: Might be. Can you please try without using any proxy? I mean just the URL directly as it is.. Also please do try the alternative way, I have added above and let me know if that works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66512/discussion-between-maduri-and-subh).

Comment: Thanx lot. Finally I found the problem. Very sorry for that. Before come to the upload page there was a another button had to click. Very sorry for waste your valuable time. Your first mentioned  code worked for me. Thanx lot and sorry. Have a nice day :).

Comment: @Maduri : Glad it worked out finally for you.. :) No need to be sorry.. To err is human.. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Use simple send keys to upload

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[value='file']")).sendKeys("C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\Saifurs\Test.html");
driver.findElementBy.cssSelector("[value='Upload']")).click();
```

Comment: Not worked. Even not file open. What type of click should I give? How to get id or name? My code showing file is selected and then upload button click not working. Give error wrong about id/name.

Comment: There is no id in the html you provided. You have to use xpath or css selector according to the html snippet you provided. And, file upload does not require `click()` simple send key should upload file

Comment: How should I change the code? Your code also doesn't even browse a file. How I get xpath or css? Can you explain little?

Comment: Selenium file upload does not require file browse or open extra window or anything else. try my edited code and just provide the absolute filepath

Comment: I added image also. Yep I tried. But didn't upload. What should I change?

Comment: Point to `Browse` element to file upload and then perform click on `Upload` element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66505/discussion-between-saifur-and-maduri).

Answer (score -2):

Try this once

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("input field")).sendKeys("path of the file which u want to upload");
```

Input field means the `xpath` of the `inputbox`.